# Umbraco is not uploading the files like .pdf or other files with higher volume

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, umbraco, umbraco7

I am working on Umbraco 7 I am getting an issue on umbraco file upload. I have not used any regular expression for uploading. I am trying to upload a pdf with file size 10MB approximately, It's working fine when I tried it on LocalHost but when I try to upload it on Live server it gave an error (displayed in image 01[image: Error screen 1])

I have tried to track this error in Firebug but didn't get any useful information.
[image: Firebug error details]

Can someone help me out in this problem?

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue? Have you given the `App Pool` user write permissions on the destination directory?

Comment: It's not permission issue I have already tried it. If this will be a permission issue then none of file will be upload, but it uploading small files easily.

Comment: Right, sorry. Didn't notice you said small files upload ok. Have you tried setting `maxRequestLength` in the web.config to something large enough?

Comment: Yeah I was got it I have changed my maxRequestLength and executionTimeout and it's working fine. Thanks Elad Lachmi

Comment: I'm stunned about the exception Umbraco is giving when this happens. Sometimes its nothing sometimes its the about message. I hope they are fixing this because this is not the first time i see this question. Ans the logfiles not give a clear answer either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah I got it problem was with web.config file I have added this code in  tag inside HttpRuntime and they are working fine now.

maxRequestLength="204800" 
executionTimeout="99999"